# Opencart SyntaxError during Checkout with registering account

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Anyone know solution of this Problem in `Opencart`,
when I add anything to shopping cart and go to register new user to buy that item, it show's me this [image: error], and don't go to next step.

Comment: have you use which OpenCart version ?

Answer (score 0):

Please you need to check these support link :

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=162066#p617203

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=162066#p618051